# Stroked and filled vector lines in Openlayers

Tags: openlayers-2, symbology

I am drawing vector lines, using GeoJSON, in my web application that uses Openlayers. I want the line to be displayed in yellow color with black border. I am using the following for the line styling:

```
my_layer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("my_layer", {
            styleMap: new OpenLayers.StyleMap(new OpenLayers.Style({
                    fillColor: "#ffff00",
                    strokeWidth: 6,
                    strokeColor: "#000000"            
            }))
        });
```

But 'fillcolor' does not affect line symbology. How can I achieve that effect?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't fill a line so you need to draw a thick black line and then a thin yellow line.

Comment: How can I add more than one style property to a single layer. Should it be 'Rule Based Styling'?

Comment: you need two layers or it won't work properly at the joins.